# why some functions push data before the prologue

Tags: disassembly, assembly, x86, stack, exe

i am a **newbie** in the world of **RE** ,

i start to explorer a **main entry of a classic game** from 90's
and i start to see something confuse me as a newbie

this **main entry function** start with **pushing stuff** to the stack **before** it's **prologue**
[image]

can someone explain why please .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's saving registers that might be modified by the function. Notice that you can see assignments to all three of those registers throughout the function body. Also notice at the bottom of your screenshot that the values of the registers are restored by popping them right before the return statement, such that the calling function will have the same values for those registers after the call as they did before the call.

Comment: hi @RolfRolles thanks for the answer , i was thinking about the same .